# Order JSON data in Angular (Ionic)

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need help with ordering JSON in ng-repeat. I want to order my data by item.id (from highest to lowest). I tried many tips that are over internet but maybe I'm just doing something wrong because none of them are working for me... My code:

```
$http.get('http://jastrzebieonline.pl/drogi/data/najnowsze.php')
   .success(function(res){
     $scope.news = res;
     console.log("Ok");
    })
   .error(function(data, status) {
     console.log("Error");
})

<div ng-repeat="item in news">
    <a href="{{ item.id }}">
      <img src="{{ item.image }}">
      <h2>{{ item.title }}</h2>
      <p>{{ item.date }}</p>
      <p>{{ item.text }}</p>
    </div>
    </a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Make sure your 'id' property is of type integer. Then just do `ng-repeat="item in news | orderBy:'-id'"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) filter:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in news | orderBy:'id'">
    <a href="{{ item.id }}">
      <img src="{{ item.image }}">
      <h2>{{ item.title }}</h2>
      <p>{{ item.date }}</p>
      <p>{{ item.text }}</p>
    </div>
    </a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "orderBy" filter to do the job.

By the way, you should use 'ngHref' and 'ngSrc' directives instead of the original 'href' and 'src' attribute.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in news | orderBy:'id':true">
    <a ng-href="{{ item.id }}">
      <img ng-src="{{ item.image }}">
      <h2>{{ item.title }}</h2>
      <p>{{ item.date }}</p>
      <p>{{ item.text }}</p>
    </div>
    </a>
 </div>
```

references:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Comment: Doesn't work. I tried:
item in news | orderBy: -id
item in news | orderBy: '-id'
item in news | orderBy: -item.id
item in news | orderBy: '-item.id'

I have error in console:Error: [orderBy:notarray] Expected array

Comment: Then you should add 'console.log(res)' before console.log("Ok") to see what you res is like.

Comment: res is just object
I tried to convert it but still doesn't work. I work it out:
item in news | toArray:true | orderBy: '-id'

toArray filter is here: https://github.com/petebacondarwin/angular-toArrayFilter

Comment: Well, got it.  Thx